# Need to click twice or more on a button to trigger a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know this type of question has already been asked but the answers I found never helped for my case.
So I've got a function `GameOverScreen()` which leads to the click on a button to reset everything.
When I click on my button, most of my code is done but not one particular line: `$('#gameOver').css('display', 'none');` If I want this to be done, I have to click several times on my button.

Please note that there's no click event in my HTML, it's a simple `p` with an input inside:

```
<p>Pour recommencer la partie, cliquez sur le bouton :<input type="reset" id="restart" value="Recommencer"></p>
```

Thanks in advance for your help, 
Here's my jQuery code:

```
 function gameOverScreen() {
    $('#gameOver').css('display', 'block');
    propSound[0].pause();
    $('#restart').click(reset);
};

function reset() {

    //je remets mon bouton en position "on"
    $('#start').css('margin-left', '0px');
    //mon avion reprend sa position initiale
    planeHeight.css('display', 'block');
    planeHeight.css('top', '434px');
    planeHeight.css('transform', 'rotateZ(0deg)');
    //J'arrête l'animation de mon hélice
    clearInterval(intervalIdAnimProp);
    //J'arrête l'animation de mon bg
    clearInterval(intervalIdanimBg);
    //J'arrête le son
    propSound[0].pause();
    //Le compteur se remet à zéro
    speed = '000';
    $('#speedometer').val(speed);
    //Désaffichage des mes flèches
    $('#arrows').css('display', 'none');
    $('#display').val("Afficher");
    //background
    $('#gameOver').css('display', 'none');
    bgSrc.css('background', 'url("sources/images/fond.jpg")');
};
```

EDIT : here's my HTML if necessary:

```
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mini jeux</title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="exercice17.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="exercice17.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">

        <div id="playground">
             <div id="plane">
                <img src="sources/images/avion1.png">
                <img id="prop" src="sources/images/helice.png">
            </div>
            <audio id="engine" src="sources/son/moteur.mp3" loop></audio>
            <div id="arrows">
                <section id="up"><img src="sources/images/boutons.png"></section>
                <section id="down"><img src="sources/images/boutons.png"></section>
               <section id="right"><img src="sources/images/boutons.png"></section>
               <section id="left"><img src="sources/images/boutons.png"></section>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="cmd">
            <div id="onOff">
                <span>Démarrer/arrêter :</span>
                <div id ="on"><img id="start" src="sources/images/on-off.png"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="compteur">
                <span>Vitesse :</span>
                <input type="text" id="speedometer" value="000" size="1" max='270'>
                <p>km/h</p>
            </div>
            <div id="instructions">
                <p>Après avoir démarrré, utilisez les flèches du clavier pour piloter l'avion. Sinon, vous pouvez activer/ désactiver les commandes tactiles : <input type="button" id="display" value="Afficher"></p>     </div>
            <div id="flyButton">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="gameOver">
            <h1>GAME OVER</h1>
            <p>Pour recommencer la partie, cliquez sur le bouton :<input type="reset" id="restart" value="Recommencer"></p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You can try also: `$("#reset).on("click", reset());`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but doesn't work for me either...

Comment: Have you got your browser console open? Is there anything that the console is showing when the `reset()` function is supposed to be run?

Comment: It all looks OK to me. Maybe there's something else at play that you haven't included here? What is planeHeight, presumeably some global reference to an DOM object? What the the intervals doing? Try removing elements in that reset to find out what is actually causing it to fall over.

Comment: Try to substitute the input with an anchor. Maybe the browser have some problem with that or add preventDefault inside function.

Comment: Yes it's opened, but there's nothing in here. All I can see is my HTML elements which are changing except this  $('#gameOver').css('display', 'none'); wich stays $('#gameOver').css('display', 'block');

Comment: I try to use event.preventDefault() and it didn't work for me but is it the right way to di it ? (it's inside the gameOver function)       $('#restart').click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            reset();
        });

Comment: And what do you mean by using an anchor please ? Can you show me an exemple ?

Comment: Thank you a lot guys for your help, you're really helpfull all of you ! :) (and waaay better efficient that on french forums ;)).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure about this answer, but `<input type="reset">` is used to reset all form(if there's one) values to default values. I don't think you're trying to do that here. Could you try changing the `type` of your input button to something like `<input type="button">` ?

Comment: Thank for your answer, finally the 'visibily', 'hidden' works.

Answer (score 0):

It could also possibly work better if you make its visibility hidden. (not entirely sure as your code seems very specific).

Something like:

```
$('#gameOver').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: And the winner is... :) Thank you it works !! I don't know why 'display' 'none' doesn't work but I will think of this solution from now on !

Comment: Sweet. Please upvote me so I can actually write comments :D

Comment: Well if you told me how to do so, with pleasure !

Comment: I believe its the up arrow next to the my main answer post. There is also a way to have mine be your selected answer.